# Target "debug" does not exist in the project

Tags: android, ant, build.xml

I am trying to do custom build, hence I am editing build.xml file. I have added 2 new targets, but now NetBeans are giving me error, when trying to debug - Target "debug" does not exist in the project.But I have added target of different names, no debug at all! Does it mean I have to put in my build.xml all the content from **android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml** ?

Comment: do you have local.properties in your project? if not, try android update project -p . in root directory of your project.

Comment: yes, I have local properties in my project

Answer (score 0):

In build.xml, you'll neet to add the target.

Add these lines inside `<project>`:

```
<target name="debug" description="generate the distribution">
    <mkdir dir="dist"/>
    <jar jarfile="dist/MyProject.jar" />
</target>
```